# Does a person get instant Brahma-Gyaan on seeing the Vishwa-Roop of Krishna?

Tags: krishna, knowledge, vishwaroop

Is it true that a person gets instant Gyaan on seeing Vishwa-Roop of Krishna? (The same Vishwa-Roop that he showed to Arjun.)

Comment: Arjuna had the vision of Isvara, Saguna Brahman. He did not have Brahma Jnana, the experience of Nirguna Brahman.

Answer (score -1):

It is the other way around. One envisions the Vishva Rupa once the Brahma Jnana is attained.
Vishva Rupa is nothing but an attempt to understand the form of existence. We equate existence with creation, in other words, the universe. Therefore we mistake Vishva Rupa to be the form of the entire creation.

A form is recognized only by its borderlines. Can anyone "see" the borderlines of the Universe? No, because it is infinite; there are no borderlines, and yet, the infinite universe is only a "part" of existence in the sense, there exists something that "controls" the physical infinity. This something was named Brahman by our sages and also described as "God" in popular terminology.

Vishva Rupa, therefore, is a comprehensive, all-embracing vision of existence where in the seer and the seen merge. That is why this "seeing" is not possible with the physical eyes.